# The [master] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag has 513 really scattered questions and has no wiki/excerpt.

Based on the "related tags" it seems that this tag is used for:

- source control (especially [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)) master branches
- half of ASP.NET [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages)
- half of [master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-slave)
- half of [master-detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-detail)
- something to do with "master replication" (I have no idea what this is).

What should be done about this tag?  A full burnination?

Comment: If there is no master, there is no spoon, so there are no slaves... Which means, all of the tagged questions seem to have other tags identifying them better, that makes the `master` quite useless.

Comment: master-replication sounds like master-slave most likely.

Comment: All the [tag:master-slave] questions are probably `off-topic; questions about hardware`.

Comment: @TylerH actually it looks like it's being used more like a design pattern inspired by that hardware setup.

Comment: There are specific questions relating to SQL Server's `master` system database, these should probably be moved to a new tag like [tag:master-db]

Comment: All SQL Server questions I can see have been migrated to [tag:master-db] now. MySQL Replication looks like it needs dealing with also

Comment: I went to look into this and found that [tag:master-slave]'s description claims "A metaphor that may be offensive and is currently being deprecated. Prefer source-replica or main-copy when possible." - but there aren't [tag:source-replica] or [tag:main-copy] tags.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's a discussion for another meta post. Fair warning though, the opinions surrounding the master term are highly polarized, and comes with all the fun that entails

Comment: Oh, I'm fully aware. I was just amused by the seeming internal contradiction.

Comment: **PSA:** this burnination has absolutely nothing to do with GitHub et.al's decision to deprecate master as a branch name. The tag, as used on Stack Overflow, and as outlined in both the question and Lundin's answer, is ambiguous regardless of the politics surrounding the name. That's the focus of a burn, not politics and shifts in naming standards. If you have a reason why it isn't _ambiguous_ (nothing to do with the politics around the rename; that's not why we're here. That's an applicable topic for renaming tags, not for burning them), post an answer

Comment: See also [the criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/6296561), which lay the foundation for tag removal (and along with it, arguments against removing a tag)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: On the other hand, swapping out slave for something more fitting is universally supported. In any case, a git question tagged master needs a better tag (main clearly isn't any better)

Comment: @Joshua that sounds an awful lot like a rename reason, not a burnination reason. Ran out of characters initially, but renaming tags can take shifts in public opinion into play. Burninations do not. Some renames may bring a disambiguation with it, but still a different system from outright removing a tag. But yeah, that still doesn't make master or main good tags, and any such renames are a separate discussion entirely

Comment: I would point out that if we decide to burninate this tag, it shouldn't be replaced with [tag:main]!

Comment: Is it possible to conditionally replace this tag with `mysql-master`, `<VCS_NAME>-master` (or `vcs-master` simply), `aspnet-master`?

Comment: @galeksandrp No. vcs-master does not make sense. We do not make tags for naming conventions. Can't comment on the other two, but unless it's a special construct specific to mysql or asp.net, it shouldn't have a tag. And for balance, `vcs-main` isn't a good tag either for the exact same reason vcs-master isn't a good tag

Comment: @KarlKnechtel IMO neither master-slave, source-replica nor main-copy makes sense. The tag should be master-slave-replication for example. I suspect whoever wrote that usage guidance didn't think it through too much.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in fact I have now replaced the usage guidance with something I think is more useful, although the tag should perhaps still be burninated.

Answer (score 57):

Yes, we should burninate this.

---

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is very ambiguous and is used for all manner of diverse topics, from data communication protocols, Git, algorithm theory, MySQL and so on.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Not stand-alone, no.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Not really. The other tags are required to explain the topic and context.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Not at all; see 1.

Answer (score 24):

[master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- **DO NOT** replace the [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag with [main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/main), or other tags to indicate branch name preferences. Tags are not meant to include branch names.

  - Questions about Git should be tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), and equivalently for any other VCS systems.
  - Questions about GitHub should be tagged [github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github), and equivalently for other [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) hosts.
- Questions about [ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) master pages can be tagged [master-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-pages)
- Questions about the master/slave pattern can be tagged [master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-slave).

  - If anyone wants to rename the [master-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-slave) tag, [post a separate meta question](/questions/ask) (using the [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag. Remember to check for an existing question first.); we're not addressing that issue in the burnination itself.
  - If the question is tagged [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) and any of [head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/head), [main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/main), [branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/branch), [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) or other git related tags, remove those as well. We are not burninating those yet, but they will be revisited later.
  - Questions about the pattern applied for hardware should be closed as "Not about programming or software development" instead
- Questions about the master-detail interface pattern can be tagged [master-detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-detail)
- Questions about the `master` system database in [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) can be tagged [master-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master-db)

## Progress:

The [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=master),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaster%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=298343) (not functioning properly; stats may be incomplete)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: seems like [master-slave] should be burninated (eventually) not because it's offensive, but because it doesn't refer to any specific technology or concept (just like [master])

Comment: @user253751 make a new meta post with that proposal then

Answer (score 6):

"Master" as a concept is heavily context-dependent, therefore, there are better tags that should be used instead, since those already cover the topic being asked about. [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) (although in this particular case I would be very suspicious that these are on-topic), [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) (ditto), [jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins) (ditto), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), etc. The tag and what it represents in those contexts isn't a new topic that hasn't been asked before, as the tagging help page suggests that should be considered when creating a tag. Those questions are fine without this tag and without anything that replaces it. BTW, if you find a question with [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) as a tag, remove those too.

Answer (score -17):

Burnination sounds fun! Although tags such as [master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/master) are less profound within the Stack Overflow community, these tags imply categorical morphisms in a much broader sense. Suppose, you have two tags [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql). The concerned tag may be used with both. Thus, there exists some morphism between the [slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slave) and [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) tags which would otherwise be unknown upon burnination.

1. That said, where will these morphisms be put to use?

   Knowledge bases are graph theoretical constructs which takes advantage of these morphisms.
2. The concerned tag is ambiguous, meaningless, and thus, useless. Why shouldn't we burninate it?

   For now, yes. Just as a person learns more about something, he builds relations to describe the thing better. Those relations may be logical, empirical, or subjective. But he learns over time. Considering the community to be a huge knowledge base, there are undiscovered relations (or morphisms). With progress in NLP and Graph-based AI, who knows if new relations come up, putting the `master` tag as more useful. But if we burninate the same now, these semantics would be lost (or such progress will be affected).
3. Is there any other tag which faces the same dilemma?

   Another profound knowledge base like Stack Overflow is the Wikipedia. If we consider the titles instead of tags, "philosophy" is a title associated with many other titles, in the sense that if you click the first link of any article you will eventually reach it.
4. Is the tag on-topic for the site?

   Tags are build to index QnA, so, if there exists an on-topic question using the tag, the tag must be on-topic.

Comment: Tags should be able to work as the only tag on the question, since to be created it needs to cover a topic that hasn't been asked before. All the topics you mention are either off topic or already covered.

Comment: An off-note: what's up with quote formatting - are you citing someone?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine The quote format was introduced by an editor to replace code format. Not sure why they preferred quotes over plain text.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine oh, thanks, I failed to notice! The question stands, I suppose, but I am more inclined to edit them out now.

Comment: I was a bit hesitant to edit the brand name in the quote because of that formatting. If it's not a quote at all, but just someone's misunderstanding of formatting, let's clean it up...

Comment: Although this answer appears to be attempting to apply mathematical theory to ontology (in the [information science sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_\(information_science\)))