# Urgh, there exists a "web3.0" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Seriously, what value do these have: [web2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web2.0) (x106) [web3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3.0) (x14)

and would anyone miss them if I started editing them out of questions?

Comment: With 24 and 2 followers respectively...I'd go for it....and this question is way on the nose [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018636/what-is-web-2-0-and-web-3-0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018636/what-is-web-2-0-and-web-3-0)

Comment: Ugh, burninate all the meaningless buzzword tags!

Comment: Could you wait for Meta consensus (like an upvoted answer) before going in an edit spree? If not, why even post to Meta?

Comment: @Kyll Only just checked back 10 minutes ago - a 3rd were already gone and 10 votes to 1 in 13 hours.  How long should I wait?

Comment: Why don't you simply voice your opinion in an answer (_"These tags hold no value and should just disappear"_) and see how it goes from here? Upvotes on this question could either mean than people agree with you that those tags should disappear, or maybe they think that they're indeed worth taking a look at to improve them. An answer would draw the line more precisely, I think.

Comment: @Emissary Re. "How long should I wait?" See Shog's post about the [new process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/176646) for burninate requests.

Comment: @all When I came back to Meta, I saw many had already been removed and mistakenly took that as tacit approval - I apologise if I stood on any toes. I'll refrain from making any edits on SO if it's easier for anyone wishing to review the posts related to the tag in my history. Unless the general feeling is I should revert my changes until this is resolved?

Comment: What @Kyll said, plus, this is a vote on two tags. Web 3.0 sounds silly at first, and at a glance, I'm not a fan of "Web 2.0" either. But perhaps someone comes up with a good reason for these tags to exist that neither of us thought of yet, at which point we can both say "hey, I hadn't looked of it that way, you're right, these tags are worth keeping!" ... None of this is really reflected in "an upvote", neither are nuanced like "Web 3.0 is useless, but Web 2.0 is worth keeping because so-and-so ..." :-)

Comment: Also note that just editing tags out of questions is not really a nice way to remove a tag, since you're still leaving potentially off-topic or improvable content lying around... And those posts are now more difficult to find! This is why [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) has proposed a [process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process) to handle burnination.

Comment: @Emissary Sorry, that was me. There was a lot of *really bad* questions in these tags, and I closed and deleted a bunch of them because they needed to go away, regardless of the outcome of this tag. I should've posted a comment, but I spaced it off.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Okay, in the interest of objectivity - as suggested in the comments - here is an answer you can vote on.  I think the tags should be eradicated as the term/s ***web x.0*** are fuzzy.  There are no formal definitions, they are ambiguous and as such have little taxonomic value in and of themselves.  On top of this the kind of questions where they *may* be applicable are subjective and therefore not suited to the Stack Overflow Q&A format anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time today re-tagging, close voting and cleaning up those remaining questions. The last bits were handled during a Close Vote event of the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room tonight.

Assuming no-one rolls-back my edits or create a new question with [web2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web2.0) the tag will be completely gone at 03:00 UTC. And then it is time to flag for a moderator to declare this [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) as [web3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web3.0) is already gone.

Answer (score -18):

The term [Web 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0) is fairly well defined. The fact that they've made the internet a more centralized place means I'm a bit nostalgic for Web 1.0, but that is neither here nor there.

However, it doesn't seem like a useful tag for Stack Overflow in particular. Questions such as how to add wiki-like functionality shouldn't be tagged with web 2.0. It should have tags such as the web development framework you're using instead. It might be relevant on other Stack Exchanges, however.

(Declaration of interest: I did some work that was kind of related to a [web site](http://eol.org/) that's been dubbed a Web 2.0 website)

Comment: Except this is about [tag:web3.0] as well, not just [tag:web2.0].

Comment: @QPaysTaxes true, but I'm more familiar with the latter than the former.

Comment: What qualifies as web 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0 seems completely arbitrary to me...  Especially when you see blogs and CMSs listed as web 2.0, but wikis and dynamically generated pages via server side technologies being listed as 1.0.  They're marketing buzzwords, nothing more.

Comment: Not *completely* arbitrary. There are some consistent descriptions of what constitutes web 2.0 (e.g. AJAX) as opposed to 1.0. But I agree that the boundaries are plenty fuzzy.

Comment: It may be hard to tell whether a withering plant has truly died yet, but that doesn't mean there is a difference between an alive plant as a dead plant. Likewise just because it's hard to tell the boundary between web 1.0 and web 2.0 doesn't mean they don't exist as different things. geocities page: obviously 1.0. Something like https://strongcoin.com/ , obviously web 2.0.