# Let's increase the rep needed to create new tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

> create tags
>   Privilege type: Creation privilege
>   Awarded at: 1,500 reputation

Can we please change this to

> create tags
>   Privilege type: Creation privilege
>   Awarded at: high reputation

Something <strike>a bit</strike> much higher than 1,500.
It would cut down significantly on the proliferation of tags.

When SO just started and tags where rare it made sense to have a low bar for new tags, but now that it's grown so huge. The tag bar really ought to be raised.

I guess this should be a function of the number of users with high rep, so that the bar to create tags goes up as the number of users with high rep increases.

Comment: I, for one, can't wait to have dozens of newly-created JS library maintainers come to meta to ask for a tag.

Comment: @SeinopSys, No let's have a clean-up and burnination of dozens of silly tags instead.

Comment: @Johan, I do not see the proliferation of tags you're speaking of. Can you provide links to evidence?

Comment: I think that is a little drastic of a change. However, I would be interested if you were to analyze the whole set of privileges considering the current reputation spectrum now versus when they were designed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the large number of burnination requests flooding meta day after day comes to mind.

Comment: @Johan, that number hasn't changed much since I joined I'm afraid -- the only (relatively) new thing is the obligatory puns in the requests' titles, which *may* have made these requests more popular.

Comment: 20K seems a bit over the top

Comment: @JustDoIt, yes a bit over the top. 1500 seems a bit low and the cleanup of tags is soo much work. We could do with less of them.

Comment: 5K seems more reasonable, I'm low rep but even if creating tags were 5 rep privilege I wouldn't really use it, all the tags I need have been already created.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi On the [moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today) (10k link), there is a list of created tags for today, up to 30 days ago. Each day, at least ~15 tags are created. They may be warranted (that isn't my point) but there are indeed a lot of created tags.

Answer (score -1):

You realize that SO already has a higher bar for creating tags than other sites right?

If the bar is set this high, it will certainly be exclusionary towards people who are active in niche areas. While they could come to Meta, the whole idea of [tag-pls](/questions/tagged/tag-pls) is annoying enough as it is and this will only serve to increase those numbers.

Personally, I have created just one tag ([bold-delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bold-delphi)). I have earned this right and I do not like that you are suggesting that I lose it because *others* are abusing it.

I understand that there are a lot of bad tags that are created (because I actually have been working to clear some of these). But 20k rep is just too high. (Edit: I see you have edited and you now think it should be awarded at a nonspecific "high reputation". Since you have not given another number, I just assume that you still mean 20k rep.)

If you want to help with the  overwhelming number of tags, you can work on eliminating some of the smaller tags. According to [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/6083675):

> it's worth noting that none of this particularly matters for tags that only have a tiny handful of questions in them; if one person can knock out a tag in a few minutes, then a huge heavy process surrounding it is completely unnecessary... You don't really even need to bring it up on meta. But you should still use good judgement, even for small tags. If the tag isn't actively causing harm, leave it be.

Comment: I do feel it's too easy to create tags and too hard to get rid of them.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which tag did you create?

Comment: @TravisJ Bold-delphi.