# Drop [tortoise] synonym of [tortoisesvn]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

Right now [tortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoise) is a synonym of [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn). However, there are several Tortoise* clients nowadays such as [tortoisecvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisecvs), [tortoisegit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisegit), [tortoisehg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisehg) and TortoiseSVN and, therefore, I think that [tortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoise) is not a good synonym for [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn) any more.

That's why I suggest to drop the [tortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoise) synonym of [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn).

Comment: This makes good sense, but I'll wait a bit for the community to weigh in before actioning it. The only issue that occurs to me is what to do with the [tortoise] tag. Should it be a generic tag for all of the Tortoise* shell extensions? Or do we just remove it and hope no one uses it?

Comment: Not all Tortoise* clients share code, so I'm unsure whether it makes sense to keep as a generic tag for all clients. However, (iirc) most share/reuse TortoiseOverlays a library for providing shell overlay icons.

Comment: Is the UI the same for the others as for Tortoise SVN? As in, does it make sense to have a [tag:tortoise] tag at all? For generic UI-related questions?

Comment: As I already said, not all Tortoise* tools share code and, thus, the UI is also not identical. Also, the Tortoise* tools are developed by independent developers.

Comment: @MrTux "shell overlay" hey? I see what's been done there...:)

Comment: There are a lot of tortoise clients but how many questions are there about non TortoiseSVN clients?

Comment: At least the tortoisehg tool is radically different from tortoisesvn @Lundin, I'm not even sure if it actually provides shell overlay functionality on Windows (I've only use it on Linux, where it works roughly similar to `gitk`, except better).

Comment: Yes, TortoiseHg on Windows provides a shell extension with icon overlay support, just like TortoiseSVN. The UI is not identical for all the products, but they certainly share much of the design (to the extent that the underlying source control technologies make it practical). On the other hand, a [[tag:shell-extensions]] tag already covers these commonalities, so I'm inlined to think that [[tag:tortoise]] is a tag that simply should not exist.

Answer (score -11):

Burninate [tortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoise) tag and keep those specific tags only: [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn), [tortoisegit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisegit), [tortoisehg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisehg), [tortoisecvs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisecvs) and [tortoisewhatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisewhatever).

At the same time, I don't have any issues with having [tortoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoise) as synonym for [tortoisesvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tortoisesvn).

Comment: No burnination needs to be done here... [[tag:tortoise]] is currently a synonym of [[tag:tortoisesvn]], so we basically either remove the synonym mapping and [[tag:tortoise]] becomes an unused tag, or we leave it as it is.

Comment: @CodyGray leave it as-is in this case. :)

Comment: @CodyGray noob here - what's the difference between "removing the synonym mapping" and "burninating"?

Comment: [Burninating](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124) is a process where we go through and remove the tag from all questions that currently have it. It requires manual editing (drudgery), and since it's so disruptive and time consuming, we require that it be accompanied by general clean-up (making your retag edits count, closing off-topic questions, deleting garbage, etc.). Removing a synonym mapping is a one-click operation in the moderator tools, just like creating a synonym mapping. @gkubed