# Do we support [production-support]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

For me it's a simple decision, but I might be wrong.

[production-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/production-support)

> Production support is the practices and disciplines of supporting the IT systems/applications which are currently being used by the end users. A production support person/team is responsible for receiving incidents and requests from end-users, analyzing these and either responding to the end user with a solution or escalating it to the other IT teams. These teams may include developers, system engineers and database administrators.

That tag is 8 years old and has 11 questions.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. It describes a process of a company, which is not related to the technical problem.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

IMHO, no.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The description is too vague, applies to several departments and people. It does not clarify anything technical

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Even if it does, the 3 items before will kill it.

Comment: I support producing a flame thrower to burn the tag to the ground ;)

Comment: Why do we care about meta?, lets kill it only 11 questions and be done with it

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!  Don't just *do* that!!

Comment: @Makoto there are so few question that according to me Thomas or any other user like you can without problem just go ahead cv and remove that tag, we better just clean this stuff up and bring the big stuff to meta, you really like to involve all meta for 11 questions and a tag like production-support?

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  **Yes.** There are questions which should be ***deleted***.  Do *not* just edit them all on your own, whatever you do.  This creates a mess in that we can''t find low-quality questions and do the proper moderation on them.

Comment: @Makoto I have more then 2K, I'm trusted to edit, I think you are making a big issue of a small problem that users normally can handle by them self. A mess? are you joking?, have you seen the front page of SO? You have no idea how many tags I have removed that have 5-15 questions, mostly class name in jasper-report, it's part of our job, you really like me to bring each one to meta?

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  [You should have a read at the burnination process.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto ooh I have, but there is a threshold on number of questions when we need to use this, now let me see if I can find some meta or maybe it's only in chat when writing it, I also have participate in most of them from godaddy to apple (it's lots of work...).

Comment: @Makoto if you read it, you will see it means to involve mods, feature on meta etc etc, you really really think this is need for 11 questions? with production-support tag, do we (including mods) not have better things to do?

Comment: @PetterFriberg:  All I'm really asking you to do is to not remove the tag from *every* question here.  I get that 11 questions is very few, but that doesn't mean that we should just go in guns blazing and nuke every occurrence of the tag.  That's more counterproductive than it is helpful.  So I'm more or less bastardizing the process in preserving its intent; we don't want to edit bad questions, and we don't want good questions to go back into the wild unpolished.

Comment: I'm not removing from every question, I edit what I think is an on-topic question and cv what I think is not, normal clean up style, if you and Thomas do the same in 5 minutes we are done, in 3 days (still 10K ;) we delete what is not useful, I can send some stuff for review to SOCVR for quick review. It's just crazy to make a burnation process for 1-20 question, if we stop commenting we can clean this up quickly

Comment: @Makoto it's actually written in the meta you sent me, the threshold is 50 "If you have authoritative knowledge of technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help."

Comment: *I remembered only 1-20, but yeah it was probably raised to avoid to many request on meta*

Comment: @PetterFriberg you're absolutely right (@Makoto that post was changed yesterday to add that). I think this tag qualifies for a "quick burn" as outlined there, note that the quick burn doesn't require opening a topic on meta, you just need to have knowledge, and confer with at least one other trusted member (you can probably use one of the chat rooms for that, I guess SOCVR is your best bet)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Interesting it was edited by Cody in fact I think I remembered right rene (SOCVR) was more around the 1-20 threshold, but I think Cody's decision is correct. To sum up, let's just hit and cv what has to be cv:ed and save what has to be save'd, still some cv to go, so check it out!

Comment: @petter Yeah, I edited it, but prior to my edit, it still said "around 50". I personally think that's a bit too many, and would prefer to see the threshold at half that, but I didn't feel comfortable changing it without being knowledgeable about the prior discussion. If you remember SOCVR agreeing with ~25, then let's change it to that.

Comment: Still, quite obvious that 11 questions doesn't need a Meta discussion, unless you're unsure. If you are, ask on Meta, get a little consensus going, and then remove it. No need for the full burnination process. That's the intent of the guidelines. Remember, though: burnination is a clean-up process, no matter on what scale it is done. That means you don't just snip the tag out of all the questions it's attached to. You also clean up the questions. If they're off-topic, you close them and/or delete them. If they're not, you edit the tag out while fixing other problems.

Comment: @Cody my number is only a vague memory, about discussions when/if we could clean up tags without meta or not, that you can clean yourself if few questions is from this [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307124/5292302) by Shog9 (see end). I guess any number between 15-50 is a good number.

Comment: I think we never really decided on the threshold but just used common sense. The common  sense back then (2015,early 2016) was 50 and that is reflected in the [burnination priority query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/493425/burninate-priority-list). It says `where qc.qcount > 50`, so we considered back then anything under 50 questions to be processed by a single person in one seating, above 50 qualified for the full blown process. /cc @CodyGray  (I'll ping Petter in the SOCVR room)

Comment: How about [production-code]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you get started, there's a few things we want to do:

- **Determine if anything here is salvageable.**  Looking it over I'm thinking, "maybe not", but look them over.  There's only a handful of 'em.
- For questions which can be saved, **edit them into shape**.  For questions which can't be saved, **close and do *not* edit them**.
- Those without the privilege of editing everywhere need not apply.